# AWS Lambda - extremely slow on doing 1000 async calls

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a serverless python app that I'm deploying to Lambda.

The app does 1000 async fetch calls that normally take 5-10s on my machine (or an EC2). On lambda however they're taking up to a minute:
[image]

I've tried increasing memory up to the max of 10gb, that doesn't solve the issue. What else might be causing this?

In case helpful, the code fetches transactions from the Solana blockchain using a private RPC node, the function looks like this:

```
    @retry_with_backoff(11)  # max wait about 3.5min
    async def fetch_sigs(self, marketplace, before=None, until=None, limit=5):
        async with AsyncClient(self.url) as client:
            sigs = (await client.get_signatures_for_address(SOL_MARKETPLACES[marketplace],
                                                            before=before,
                                                            until=until,
                                                            limit=limit)
                    ).get("result", [])
            print(f'Fetched a total of {len(sigs)} sigs')
            return sigs

    @retry_with_backoff(11)
    async def fetch_single_tx_details(self, sig, attempts_to_refetch_missing_result=0):

        async with AsyncClient(self.url) as client:
            tx = await client.get_transaction(sig)

            # sometimes the result comes back as null for no apparent reason - we want to retry
            if not tx["result"] and attempts_to_refetch_missing_result < 10:
                # however, sometimes it's also just a bad tx, so we're capping to X retries
                if attempts_to_refetch_missing_result > 0 and attempts_to_refetch_missing_result % 3 == 0:
                    print('Retrying tx with empty result', attempts_to_refetch_missing_result + 1)

                return await self.fetch_single_tx_details(sig,
                                                          attempts_to_refetch_missing_result + 1)

            return tx
```

Comment: What does the code do exactly? What does it call? Which language? Relevant code snippet ?

Comment: I doubt those details will help you answer the question (I think it's more of a lambda config issue) - but I've edited the post and added actual code, in case helpful

Comment: Well, lambda should assume your role, so should use your limits. If it is not connected to your vpc, it likely uses different network routing, but that should not be a problem either, more memory implies also more CPU, but how many cores? I don't remember, if you get more cores with lambda. Lambda also support python  3.8 or so, what is the python version on your EC2?

Comment: There should be metrics published on Cloudwatch regarding Lambda latency and error rates, are there any useful insights in there?

Comment: Well the timestamp in your logs are all the same - are you calling out to the open internet? Reduce your code to 1000 network calls and rule out your code being the issue.

Comment: Could you please provide advice if you find a solution to your problem? I'm facing the same issue and would appreciate any guidance you can offer. @ilmoi